# Makefile patsubst using value of shell variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

As part of a make install rule for a testing suite, I'd like to move all binary executables in one directory (a src directory) to a bin directory.  I thought an easy way to do this would be to simply loop over each file in the `src` directory and then use `patsubst` to replace `src` with `bin` in each path.  Unfortunately, I can't get it to work because I can't get `make` to evaluate the name of the current FILE in each loop iteration.  All I have access to is the bash shell variable `$$FILE`, but when I use this with the `make` `patsubst` function, it doesn't actually *evaluate* the shell variable `$$FILE`... rather, the `patsubst` function seems to just see the string `"$FILE"`.

So, here is what I'm trying:

```
install :
    -- irrelevant stuff snipped --

    for FILE in $(BINARY_TARGETS); do \
        if [ -f $$FILE ]; then mv -f $$FILE $(patsubst %/src/,%/bin/,$$FILE); fi \
    done
```

This results in an error for each file:

```
mv: ‘./src/foo/bar’ and ‘./src/foo/bar’ are the same file
```

This error leads me to understand that the `patsubst` function in `make` is not actually evaluating shell variables, but just sees `$FILE`, and so the result is that it doesn't find the substitution pattern, and the final command passed to `mv` has the source and destination path as the same string.

So, is there a way to get `patsubst` to evaluate the value of a shell variable?  Or is there a better way in general to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` processing has a precedence over passing commands to shell. And, once passed, they are executed by shell. So, at first `make`, processes the command and in:

```
$(patsubst %/src/,%/bin/,$$FILE)
```

`$$FILE` is substituted by `$FILE` and then treated literally. So, no pattern is matched and in effect `patsubst` returns `$FILE`. Please see following example:

```
bar:
    echo $(patsubst %/src/,%/bin/,$$whatever)
```

It gives:

```
arturcz@szczaw:/tmp/m$ make bar
echo $whatever

arturcz@szczaw:/tmp/m$
```

As a result of your makefile rule bash is given following command to execute:

```
for FILE in src/a src/b src/c; do \
    if [ -f $FILE ]; then mv -f $FILE $FILE; fi \
done
```

and that's why you got your result.

### Solution

You can rely on `bash` to do a proper substitution, but you need to enforce it as a shell (by default it is `sh`, which lacks some required features):

```
SHELL=bash

install:
    for FILE in $(BINARY_TARGETS); do \
        if [ -f $$FILE ]; then echo $$FILE $${FILE/\/src\//\/bin\/}; fi \
    done
```

You can also ask `make` to do a loop and substitution. There are few ways you can achieve that. This one is doing all the replacement and prepares command on the fly.

```
install:
    $(foreach d,$(BINARY_TARGETS),if [ -f $(d) ]; then mv -f $(d) $(d:./src/%=./bin/%);fi;)
```

You can cease checking existence of files to `make` too by using `$(wildcard) function:

```
install:
    $(foreach d,$(wildcard $(BINARY_TARGETS)),mv -f $(d) $(d:./src/%=./bin/%);)
```

And, finally, solution which I personally prefer - do it in a `make` way using a proper dependencies and rules.

```
install: $(BINARY_TARGETS:./src/%=./bin/%)

bin/%: src/%
    mv -f $< $@
```

If existence any of files in `BINARY_TARGET` is optional, you may want to use the `$(wildcard)` trick again:

```
install: $(patsubst ./src/%,./bin/%,$(wildcard $(BINARY_TARGETS)))

bin/%: src/%
    mv -f $< $@
```